# How to query on embedded documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa919a49bbe481d117506c9"),
    "isDeleted" : 0,
    "productId" : 31,
    "references" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fa919a49bbe481d117506ca"),
            "languageCode" : "en",
            "languageId" : 1,
            "productId" : ObjectId("5fa919a49bbe481d117506ba")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fa91cc7d7d52f1e389dee1f"),
            "languageCode" : "ar",
            "languageId" : 2,
            "productId" : ObjectId("5fa91cc7d7d52f1e389dee1e")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-09T10:27:48.859Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-09T10:27:48.859Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f9aab1d8e475489270ebe3a"),
    "isDeleted" : 0,
    "productId" : 21,
    "references" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f9aab1d8e475489270ebe3b"),
            "languageCode" : "en",
            "languageId" : 1,
            "productId" : ObjectId("5f9aab1c8e475489270ebe2d")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-29T11:44:29.852Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-29T11:44:29.852Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is my mongoDB collection in which i store the multilingual references to product collection. In productId are the references to product Collection. Now If we have ar in our request, then we will only have the productId of ar languageCode. If that languageCode does not exist then we will have en langCode productId.

For Example if the user pass ar then the query should return

```
 "productId" : ObjectId("5fa91cc7d7d52f1e389dee1e")
 "productId" : ObjectId("5f9aab1c8e475489270ebe2d")
```

I have tried using $or with $elemMatch but I am not able to get the desired result. Also i am thinking of using $cond. can anyone help me construct the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can acheive

- `$facet` helps to categorized the incoming documents
- In the `arArray`, we get all documents which has`"references.languageCode": "ar"` (This document **may or may not** have `en`), then de-structure the `references` array, then selecting the `"references.languageCode": "ar"` only using `$match`. `$group` helps to get all productIds which belong to `"references.languageCode": "ar"`
- In the `enArray`, we **only** get documents which have only `"references.languageCode": "en"`. Others are same like `arArray`.
- `$concatArrays` helps to concept both arArray,enArray arrays
- `$unwind` helps to de-structure the array.
- `$replaceRoot` helps to make the Object goes to root

Here is the mongo script.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      arAarray: [
        {
          $match: {
            "references.languageCode": "ar"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$references"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            "references.languageCode": "ar"
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            productId: {
              $addToSet: "$references.productId"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      enArray: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                "references.languageCode": "en"
              },
              {
                "references.languageCode": {
                  $ne: "ar"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$references"
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            productId: {
              $addToSet: "$references.productId"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      combined: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$arAarray",
          "$enArray"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$combined"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$combined"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-UCgdQKe0K3)**

Comment: thanks but when i don't have 'ar' entry in my product collection it is returning empty array of produceId. instead i want the 'en' entry in my produceId.

Comment: @VishalKumar can you check is this https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ui2gldya49P correct.So I can make my answer

Comment: @VishalKumar I have made some changes, and updated the script. Have a look

Comment: @VishalKumar does this help you?

Comment: Yes it does helps me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @VishalKumar: Pease accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if this answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this solution to see if it is useful for you question:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            foundResults:
            {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $in: ["ar", "$references.languageCode"] }, then:
                    {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$references",
                            as: "item",
                            cond: {
                                $and: [{ $eq: ["$$item.languageCode", 'ar'] },
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    , else:
                    {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$references",
                            as: "item",
                            cond: {
                                $and: [{ $eq: ["$$item.languageCode", 'en'] },
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$foundResults" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$foundResults"] } } },
    { $project: { _id: 0, "productId": 1 } }
])
```